# C# method Encoding.GetEncoding won't find the windows-1252 encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

i'm trying to get the windows-1252 encoding into a local variable like this:

`Encoding win1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);`

which results in an error saying that it can't find the codepage 1252.
I've also tried looking for the Encoding via the name (both with a small w and a big one)

`Encoding win1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");`

but that also doesnt work.
I've tried looking for all Encodings my System can find with the following loop:

```
foreach(EncodingInfo ei in Encoding.GetEncodings())
{
    Encoding e = ei.GetEncoding();
}
```

And it could only find 7 in total. Do i have to install additional Encodings in any way? I'm kind of getting lost with this.

Comment: .NET Framework or .NET Core? And why do you want 1252 specifically? .NET Core applications contain only the US-ASCII and Unicode encodings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register encodings provider first to use additional encodings like `Windows-1252`.

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

[`CodePagesEncodingProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider) provides access to an encoding provider for code pages that otherwise are available only in the desktop .NET Framework.

So you can find more encodings after that and can get `Windows-1252` too:

```
Encoding win1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

> The .NET Framework for the Windows desktop supports a large set of Unicode and code page encodings. .NET Core, on the other hand, supports only the following encodings:
>
> - ASCII (code page 20127), which is returned by the Encoding.ASCII property.
> - ISO-8859-1 (code page 28591).
> - UTF-7 (code page 65000), which is returned by the Encoding.UTF7 property.
> - UTF-8 (code page 65001), which is returned by the Encoding.UTF8 property.
> - UTF-16 and UTF-16LE (code page 1200), which is returned by the Encoding.Unicode property.
> - UTF-16BE (code page 1201), which is instantiated by calling the UnicodeEncoding.UnicodeEncoding or UnicodeEncoding.UnicodeEncoding constructor with a bigEndian value of true.
> - UTF-32 and UTF-32LE (code page 12000), which is returned by the Encoding.UTF32 property.
> - UTF-32BE (code page 12001), which is instantiated by calling an UTF32Encoding constructor that has a bigEndian parameter and providing a value of true in the method call.

> Other than code page 20127, code page encodings are not supported.
> The `CodePagesEncodingProvider` class extends `EncodingProvider` to make these code pages available to .NET Core.

Note that you need a reference to `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll` to use `CodePagesEncodingProvider` in some .net versions you have to add [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/) to your project.

Comment: This worked! Crazy how i couldnt find any information on that on the internet, either i am too dumb for searching or i missed something so bad. Thank you so much!

Comment: @YouQQWhenIQ To be honest I had the same problem about a year ago and it was very difficult to understand exactly what the problem was :)